# Karate - String concatenation of JSON value with a variable

Tags: karate

I have to make a request like this:

```
And request {"ACTION":"APPROVED","COMMENT":"#(ID)"}
```

This works fine as long as i have just the #(ID) but since a comment is expected here, i wanted to do something like:

```
And request {"ACTION":"APPROVED","COMMENT":"Test Comment: #(ID)"}
```

But this does not evaluate and does not replace the variable. Is there a way to do this inline here instead of having a new variable which concatenates before and then use that here? I went through a lot of examples and could not find what i needed

Comment: because you need to read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: Oh i wish i would have found this section sooner. Thanks!